# Importing .svg images to use as Symbols in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, import, svg

I have several .svg files that I want to use as symbols in ArcMap 10.1.

However, I do not see any import feature or the sort to use these .svg pictures.

Comment: If you don't have Corel you can try to use free "Solid Edge Free 2D Drafting" which converts SVG to DXF. You can download it here:
http://www.dobreprogramy.pl/Solid-Edge,Program,Windows,12097.html
or
http://www.download.net.pl/v/25495/

Comment: This does not seem to address the question of how to get SVG into an ArcGIS symbol.

Answer (score 7):

I found a [possible solution](http://gisbiz.com/2012/06/how-to-convert-svg-files-for-arcgis/) described by GISbiz which uses Enhanced Metafiles (EMF) as an intermediary format and recommends [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) or [svg2emf](http://code.google.com/p/svg2emf/) to do the SVG to EMF conversion.

ArcMap can use Enhanced Metafiles (EMF) as a picture for [Creating a Marker Symbol](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s600000002000000) or for [Creating Fill Symbols](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s600000009000000).

As [commented by @GrantHumphries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74364/importing-svg-images-to-use-as-symbols-in-arcmap/74396#comment254937_74396):

> To bring an .emf into ArcMap do the following: select 'Customize' on
>   the top menu bar --> 'Style Manager' --> select the profile that you
>   want to add the icon to --> select 'Marker Symbols' folder --> in the
>   window for that folder right-click and select 'New' --> 'Marker Symbol
>   --> from the 'Type' drop down in the window that has opened select 'Picture Marker Symbol' --> navigate to your .emf file

Answer (score 4):

I have found that making a font file is the best way to bring in custom svg symbol. I use Fontographer to add the SVG symbols to the font, set different scales, etc. You can also use websites such as https://glyphter.com/ to make fonts.